# CSS or PHP add space in number format

Tags: php, css

How can I add a space after 3 and 4 digits ?

I have this numbers: +4420719480

The result needs to be: +44 2071 9480

How can I add the spaces with css or php after 4 characters?

I have tried the following code:

```
$str = "+4420719480";
echo chunk_split($str, 4, ' ');
```

But how do I add the space to the first 3 characters and then to the 4th?

Comment: You can revert string, use `chunk_split` and then revert again.

Comment: Anything wrong with `substr()` and concatenation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preg_replace

```
$str = '+4420719480';
echo preg_replace('~^.{3}|.{4}(?!$)~', '$0 ', $str);
```

pattern explanation:

```
~           # pattern delimiter
^.{3}       # any character 3 times at the start of the string
|           # OR
.{4}        # any character 4 times
(?!$)       # not followed by the end of the string
~           # pattern delimiter
```

replacement: `'$0 '`  (the whole pattern and a space)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but with this pattern i cannot echo the first 3 digits and then 4 by 4

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the most mundane solution will do the job just fine.

```
$str = "+4420719480";
$new = substr($str,0,3).' '.substr($str,3,4).' '.substr($str,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, you can do:

```
$str = "+4420719480";
echo strrev(chunk_split(strrev($str),4," "));
```

Kinda clunky and only works for this size of `$str`, but it works!

Comment: Exactly, this work, but if i want to start with 4 and then separe with 3 ?